# Polymer elements don't work, when loaded by XHR

Tags: ajax, polymer

I'm trying to load a document with XHR, and move some loaded nodes into the main document. The problem is that Polymer elements defined in the loaded document "don't work" after moving. They are look and behave like regular `<div>`s.

Here is a simple repro case.

Loaded document:

```
<!-- insert.html -->
<div>
  <link rel="import" href="paper-button/paper-button.html">
  <div>Hello, world!</div>
  <paper-button>I am a button</paper-button>
</div>
```

Main page:

```
<!-- index.html -->
<html>
<head>
<link rel="import" href="polymer/polymer.html">
<link rel="import" href="core-ajax/core-ajax.html">
<script>

window.addEventListener('polymer-ready', function() {
  var ajax = document.getElementById('ajax');
  ajax.addEventListener('core-response', function(e) {
    var insertTo = document.getElementById('insertion-point');
    insertTo.appendChild(e.detail.response.body.children[0]);
  });
  ajax.go();
});

</script>
</head>
<body>
  <core-ajax id="ajax" url="insert.html" handleAs="document"></core-ajax>
  <div id="insertion-point"> </div>
</body>
</html>
```

After loading I see that `#insertion-point` contains loaded document, as expected, but `<paper-button>` is not functioning and looks like `<div>I am a button</div>`.

Things don't get better when I add `<link rel="import" href="paper-button/paper-button.html">` to the main page's `<head>`.

Replacing `<core-ajax>` with a native XMLHttpRequest doesn't help as well.

I'm testing on Google Chrome 42 with the latest Polymer.

My question: is this supposed to work at all? If not, why? If yes, who's to blame?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

x-posting from [Elliott Sprehn's response the polymer-dev mailing list](https://groups.google.com/forum/?utm_medium=email&utm_source=footer#!msg/polymer-dev/medaCb8_p6c/WFA4woc28HwJ).

> This doesn't work because you're taking elements from an xhr document where there's no custom element registry and then just moving them. You need to do appendChild(document.importNode(response.body.children[0])) which will create a clone of the node, but using the document where polymer has registered the custom elements.